# Using a for loop to loop over multiple arrays in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

[Bash doesn't natively support two-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash), but I would like to simulate one.  As a minimal working example, suppose that I have two arrays, `a0` and `a1`:

```
a0=(1 2 3 4)
a1=(5 6 7 8)
```

I want to write a `for` loop that will print the third element of `a0` and `a1`.  Of course, I could do this manually with two explicit calls to `echo`:

```
echo ${a0[2]}
echo ${a1[2]}
```

But, I want to generalize this with a `for` loop.  How can I do this?

I tried the following:

```
for i in ${a0[@]} ${a1[@]}
do
echo {$i}[2]
echo ${i[2]}
echo ${i}[2]
echo ${$i[2]}
echo ${${i}[2]}
done
```

But none of those attempts are successful; I get this output:

```
{1}[2]

1[2]
chgreen.sh: line 30: ${$i[2]}: bad substitution
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What’s wrong with the accepted answer at the question you linked to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you’ve presumably learned by now from your research,
bash doesn’t support multi-dimensional arrays *per se*,
but it does support “associative” arrays. 
These are basically indexed by a string, rather than a number, so you can have, for example,

```
grade[John]=100
grade[Paul]=100
grade[George]=90
grade[Ringo]=80
```

As demonstrated (but not explained very well) in the accepted answer
of the question you linked to, indices of associative arrays can contain commas,
and so a common trick is to concatenate your individual indices (0-1 × 0-3) into a string,
separated by commas. 
While this is more cumbersome than ordinary arrays, it can be effective:

```
$ declare -A a              <-- Create the associative array.
$ a[0,0]=1
$ a[0,1]=2
$ a[0,2]=3
$ a[0,3]=4
$ a[1,0]=5
$ a[1,1]=6
$ a[1,2]=7
$ a[1,3]=8
$ for i in 0 1
> do
>     echo ${a[$i,2]}
> done
3                           <-- And here’s your output.
7
```

Answer (score 6):

You're iterating over the wrong thing. Your `for` saves each element of the array as `$i`, not the array's indices. What you want is something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
a0=(1 2 3 4)
a1=(5 6 7 8)

for ((i=0;i<${#a0[@]};i++))
do
    echo ${a0[$i]} ${a1[$i]};
done
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of the question. “I want to write a `for` loop that will print the third element of `a0` and `a1`.” The OP wants a multi-dimensional array, and he wants to be able to iterate over any index (dimension). In particular, he wants to print `${a0[2]}` and `${a1[2]}` in a way that would scale readily to a situation where he has `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, …

Comment: @Scott so you're thinking the OP wants to iterate over arrays? You are very likely right, that's not what I had understood at all. If so, your solution is just about perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd way to do it but it might be useful in some cases. The problem is that the `for` loop will resolve your arrays into their elements and treat each element  separately.

Therefore, deconstruct your arrays and make them again.

```
a0=(1 2 3 4)
a1=(5 6 7 8)
a0=${a0[@]}  # deconstruction
a1=${a1[@]}
for arr in "$a0" "$a1"; do a=( $arr ); echo ${a[2]}; done
```

Output

3

7